# What causes two versions of the same assembly to be referenced by another assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# assembly with a few Nuget dependencies that is being produced as an artifact from a TFS build. The resulting assembly has **two** different versions of the **same** assembly being included in its referenced assembly list. I'd like to understand how this occurs since I'm unsure of the consequences and didn't think it was possible in the first place. I've been unable to reproduce the problem in any kind of minimal example so far.

To elaborate, I have Company.Product.A.dll which according to .NET Reflection, Mono.Cecil, dotPeek, and ILSpy references both Company.Product.B.dll 1.0.0.0 and Company.Product.B.dll 1.0.2.0 e.g.

```
// The list of referenced assemblies below contains two versions of Company.Product.B.dll
Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Company.Product.A.dll").GetReferencedAssemblies()
```

- The underlying .csproj for Company.Product.A.dll has a single reference to Company.Product.B.dll 1.0.2.0 and an appropriate Nuget package reference to the same version.
- The Company.Product.A.dll assembly is dependent on another assembly that also references Company.Product.B.dll (I'm not sure this is significant but I'm suspicious that it might have something to do with the problem if the other assembly references an older version of Company.Product.B.dll).
- I'm not aware of any ILMerge malarkey going on during the build process but I'm still looking into that just in case.
- The build server is producing clean builds each time.
- Neither the root assembly nor the two versions of the dependent assemblies are strong named.
- There appears to be no negative consequence of the spurious assembly reference; the product that uses the assemblies *works as intended*.

The ILDasm manifest is shown below (I'm unsure what the _8 on the second reference means):

```
.assembly extern /*23000008*/ Company.Product.B
{
      .ver 1:0:2:0
}
.assembly extern /*23000009*/ Company.Product.B as Company.Product.B_8
{
      .ver 1:0:0:0
}
```

Can anyone tell me what sequence of events would lead to one assembly having references to two different versions of the same dependent assembly?

Comment: this sounds like a `namespace` issue at first glance.. have you tried cleaning the project and recompiling from there..

Comment: @MethodMan Our build server does clean builds but I can't reproduce the problem building the same solutions from my own machine so you might be on to something. What namespace issues are you referring to here?

Comment: assemblies with strong names perhaps?

Comment: @rbm Neither the root or dependent assemblies are strong named, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you use ILDASM to look at the references (instead of c#) do you get the same result ? I.e. two external references to the same named DLL ?

Comment: I know what you need to check.. I had this problem once from what I remember if you are using or including packages in your Build you should check the Package.Config against the Web.Config and comment out or remove the assembly that's old you are trying to reference 2 different Nuget packages

Comment: if regards to the `namespace` if you have 2 projects for example and these are assemblies that your have written or created in the project make sure they all have the same namespace name also you can try `aliasing` the namespace `using SomeAssembley = SomeAliasName;`

Comment: Your example is a bit confusing, since it sounds like (from the first bullet) you have a dll which has a reference to itself...

Comment: @PhillipH I've added the ILDasm manifest output which shows the two references.

Comment: `extern alias` will do this.  Could be far uglier if B has a reference to C which has a reference to an old version of B and C exposes old types in its public members.  The C# compiler got hard-ass about that in 4.5, Roslyn seems more forgiving.  A detailed MSBuild trace is required to diagnose this.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks Hans, I'll dig around the msbuild logs to see if anything leaps out (the logs that produced the assemblies I'm looking at have since been purged unfortunately).